# How to parallelize data factory custom activity?

Tags: c#, azure-data-factory

I have 600 files in grib (binary) format which I need to convert to csv format. Initially, it's a one-time conversion, but later on we will receive daily files, so I have implemented a custom C# activity to run in data factory. When I first ran this activity with a batch account with a D14 v2 VM, it converted one file at a time and each file took 20-25 minutes to convert. This adds up to more than a week, which is far too long if we need to re-run the conversion for some reason. Is there any good way to parallelize this conversion?

Both input and output files are stored in blob storage in two separate containers. The input files are ca 50 Mb each and the output files are almost 2 Gb each. The data factory activity converts all files which are found in the input container when the job starts.

I tried adding a thread pool in the custom activity to have a separate thread for each input file to parallelize the work. It works well for approx. 10 files, which takes about 40 minutes to convert, but when adding more input files at the same time the data factory job ends in a strange error without any exception info in the system.log file:

Error in Activity: Process exited with code: '-532462766'. Exception message: 'Exception from HRESULT: 0xE0434352'.

Comment: Sounds like you are exhausting that single VM. One option would be to have one custom activity per file in ADF (which would be a lot of cut and paste of JSON manually). But what about having your single ADF custom activity do nothing more than list files and queue one Azure Batch Task per file by calling the Azure Batch APIs. If you configure your Azure Batch pool you can have it spin up say 10 VMs and distribute the file conversion tasks across the VMs

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use Azure Data Lake to achieve the scalability you need. Assuming the files have some sort of structure writing some USQL to shred them, combine and convert them would work well and would be much easier to implement vs an ADF custom activity that uses batch service compute.

You would of course need to have the files in Data Lake storage instead of blob store to achieve the best performance. **But** you can use blob storage as a data source to the data lake analytics service if you have to via a wasb URL.

[image]

Lastly, you could call the USQL from data factory and specify the degree of parallelism on the activity. Also, maybe have a USQL stored procedure that you pass collections of file names to. Which again can be handled from data factory.

Check out this post: https://www.purplefrogsystems.com/paul/2017/02/passing-parameters-to-u-sql-from-azure-data-factory/

Hope this helps.

Ps. In response to the comment above. Don't copy and paste JSON! Yuk! Use PowerShell with some meta data to output the data factory pipelines using the ADF cmdlets.

Comment: I tried to use USQL for another similar task where I implemented a custom extractor, but I ran into some issues:
- The ADLA Tools for Visual Studio no longer supported Windows 7. It was possible to downgrade the ADLA Tools to an earlier version, though.
- After the downgrade, I didn't get the debugging of the USQL custom extractor to work.


Also, for the current task I use a NuGet package to read the grib files. This API expects a filename when reading the file, and in a USQL custom extractor I only get a stream, so I don't know if it's possible to use this NuGet package in USQL?

Comment: I wouldn't let Windows 7 be the reason for choosing the wrong architecture to deal with your data! Next, get the error and details for your extractor and post a question on here using the USQL tag.

Comment: Is there any way we can problematically create multiple CloudTasks from within one Custom Activity?